# How to split the sequence of numbers in numpy to become an individual number?

Tags: numpy, split, element

Appreciate anyone who has a short cut in below to help out.  Thanks in advance.

There is a one dimensional numpy array with 16 elements and shape (16,) in below

```
[' 5, 5, 5, 5, 0 ' ' 3, 3, 0, 5, 3, 5 ' ' 4, 4, 4, 0, 6, 4 ' ' 4, 4, 4, 0, 6, 4 ' ' 2, 5, 2, 5, 0, 5 ' ' 2, 5, 5, 5, 0, 5 ' ' 3, 3, 0, 5, 3, 3 ' ' 6, 4, 4, 0, 6, 4 ' ' 4, 4, 4, 0, 6, 4 ' ' 0, 1, 1, 6, 6, 3 ' ' 3, 3, 0, 3, 6, 3 ' ' 2, 0, 4, 2, 6, 4 ' ' 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0 ' ' 4, 4, 4, 0, 6, 4 ' ' 4, 4, 4, 0, 6, 4 ' ' 3, 3, 0, 6, 6, 3 ']
```

How can I split each of the elements in above and becomes a two dimensional numpy array of shape 16 X 6 like this

```
5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0 (padding one zero at the end)
3, 3, 0, 5, 3, 5
4, 4, 4, 0, 6, 4
.....

3, 3, 0, 6, 6, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The shape that you mentioned represents a rank array .
One of the way to change shape ofnumpy array is with numpy.reshape(16,6) if your previous numpy array shape was(1,96).I might help you better if you would tell me that your attempt was to make rank array.

Comment: Thanks Keshav, unfortunately the dimension of the numpy array is (16,), i.e. (16,1) that reshape doesn't work and prompt an error like this                             
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 16 into shape (16,6), I don't know if there is other way to split every element in numpy a sequence of six individual numbers.

Comment: Ya reshape doen't change no. of elements , it just arrange so reshape use requires (1,16*6) elements to be converted into(16,6). So, you actually have rank array. I have to look into it.